# Lied about future MBA specialization in interview

Tags: interviewing, human-resources, internship, lying

So the institute where I enrolled for a management program wanted us to select 4 electives for 4th semester after the end of 2nd semester and during that time I was in dilemma whether to do marketing or finance. We have 8 electives in total which are distributed equally among semester 4th and semester 5th

After the end of second semester I selected 4 marketing subjects and submitted it to college.

3rd semester is 3 months internship period which will be evaluated and has 1 semester equivalent of credits. Meaning it's very important with respect to final placements and grades.

I am now doing internship in finance and IT domain. During interview I lied that I have selected finance major and IT minor but in reality I have selected marketing subjects. I lied because I wanted this internship and I was already hitting deadline to secure an internship plus I really thought this is what I wanted to do.

I am pretty sure now that I want to take Finance major and marketing minor electives. But when I contacted college authorities about change of electives they said it's not permitted and you would be allowed to change only one elective. So now I can do 3 marketing subjects and 5 finance subjects.

My question is since the faculty will contact the HR to evaluate my internship at the company, there is a high chance that HR will get to know that I lied during interview. I am not sure what to do now. What's the best course of action now? Should I just pray it doesn't happen or go admit the mistake before they get to know from someone else?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere No, but they might question why I did internship in finance when I have selected marketing and that might affect grades.

Comment: What are you worried about- having internship company consider (or not) you for a real job after you graduate, or just about them being mad at you after the internship is over?

Comment: @Damila I am concerned about 2 things right now. My grades and The internship i.e. they don't cancel my internship.

Comment: Most likely the school will call after or near the end of the internship and ask "How did he do?" (It will be more detailed than that.) Your grade will be based on that. The internship company is going to answer about how you did; they are not going to call the school and ask "What electives did he pick for next year?" More likely, someone at the internship will ask you "So what is next for you?" You can say "Next is marketing elective, and then the first of my *five* finance electives.This has been a great experience. I wish I could do even more finance electives!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There is a non-zero chance your lie about your specialization will come to light**

If it does, the company generally do one of 4 things

1) Take you out of the running and sending you a "We're pursuing other candidates" email.  You'll have little to no chance to change this.  Learn from this and move on.

2) Not check or care about your specialization that much, not mention it, and hire you.

3) Notice and ask you for clarification.

4) Not hire you for completely unrelated reasons.

**Very few employers care about specializations (Healthcare being the big exception)**

Many college grads leave specialization off their resumes as this limits their prospect.  In reality, there very exciting jobs in finance and very terrible jobs in marketing (and vice-versa).  I'd be extremely surprised if any company held you to a specialization for the rest of your career.

If they do ask you about this, just explain that you're trying to decide between marketing and finance.  Don't lie again.  This explanation needs to be sincere.

Answer (score 1):

> I lied because I wanted this internship and I was already hitting
>   deadline to secure an internship plus I really thought this is what I
>   wanted to do.
>
> there is a high chance that HR will get to know that I lied during
>   interview. I am not sure what to do now. What's the best course of
>   action now? Should I just pray it doesn't happen or go admit the
>   mistake before they get to know from someone else?

You lied and are now worried it will be caught.

Your best bet is to remain quiet and hope it is not caught, even though you think there is a high chance that it will be.

Meanwhile, you should prepare what you will say if it should be caught and brought to your attention.

At that point brutal honesty with HR may be best, along with the assurance that you have learned a lesson about lying and don't plan to repeat that mistake.

At the same time, be prepared with what you will say to the faculty if your lie is uncovered, as a way to avoid having your grades adversely affected.

Answer (score 1):

> I am not sure what to do now. What's the best course of action now? Should I just pray it doesn't happen or go admit the mistake before they get to know from someone else?

I suggest you come clean, or at least prepare an explanation on why you did this, as it is highly probable that they will eventually find this out.

When this is found out, there is also a chance that you lose this internship opportunity. Because of that, it would be wise of you to continue applying for other internships for the case if/when this is found out.